# Creating EC2 instance and attaching it to a specific ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am using the AWS PHP SDK to create an ECS Cluster.

I am also using the AWS PHP SDK to create EC2 Instances.

I can't find API calls to create an instance, specify particular options (for instance on the spot) and adding it to the cluster I am creating. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "EC2 Cluster"? Cluster of what?

Comment: AWS ECS Cluster. The operation to create it is createCluster (EC2 Client). Usually a EC2 Instance is created in the default Cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API call for that. Instead, you specify which cluster a given instance belongs to using **user data**, as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html). So your newly launch EC2 instances should have user data in the following form:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyCluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

As well as [proper IAM instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html) allowing the ECS agent to register with your ECS cluster.